# QWebException: "'NoneType' object is not callable" while evaluating

Tags: python, xml, odoo, openerp-8

im facing a problem in qweb report, i followed this tutorial http://blog.emiprotechnologies.com/create-qweb-report-odoo/ to create qweb report, it worked fine with the static data of my current module, but when i try to create a parser class for dynamic data, i get this error " QWebException: "'NoneType' object is not callable" while evaluating " here it's my python class  :

```
from openerp.osv import osv
from openerp.report import report_sxw

class etudiant_report_parser(report_sxw.rml_parse):
   def __init__(self, cr, uid, name, context): 
    super(etudiant_report_parser, self).__init__(cr, uid, name, context=context)
    self.localcontext.update({
            'hello_world': self.hello_world,
                             })
    self.context = context

   def hello_world(self):
    return "hello"

class etudiant_object_report(osv.AbstractModel):
 _name = 'report.gestion_des_etudiants.etudiant_report'
 _inherit = 'report.abstract_report'
 _template = 'gestion_des_etudiants.etudiant_report'
 _wrapped_report_class = etudiant_report_parser
```

And in my xml file etudiant_report.xml I added this line :

```
<span t-esc=”hello_world()”/>
```

But when I print the report I get the error :

```
QWebException: "'NoneType' object is not callable" while evaluating
```

Here it's the arborescence of my module :

/report/**init**.py        <--- to load the etudiant_report.xml which contains the parser class

/report/etudiant_report.py <--- ...contains the parser class

/views/report_etudiant.xml <--- the xml file for the report

**init**.py

**openerp**.py

etudiant_view.xml

etudiant_report.xml        <--- the menu of the report

etudiant.py

Another thing I noticed, when I go into the folder " report " I don't find any .pyc file, for **init**.py and etudiant_report.py

Answer (score 0):

In order to call a custom method from the model you can do followings.

Define the method in your model

```
@api.multi
def mymethod(self):
    return "mymethod"
```

And then call the method from the qweb. here is the sample code of the qweb which is calling the custom method from the model.

```
<template id="th_custom_report">
    <t t-call="report.html_container">
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
            <t t-call="th_dynamic_report.th_report_id" t-lang="o.partner_id.lang"/>
        </t>
    </t>
</template>

<template id="th_report_id">
    <t t-call="report.external_layout">
        <t t-set="o" t-value="o.with_context({'lang':o.partner_id.lang})" />
            <span t-esc="o.mymethod()"/>
        </t>
    </t>
<template>
```

It will help you!